# how to make a legend be wrapped by a subfloat?

Tags: subfloats

I am looking to save space, by wrapping a subfloat around a legend in the following way:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aenean quis mi ut elit interdum imperdiet quis non ante.
+---------------------------+ +----------------------- +
|                           | |                        |
|      FIGURE HERE          | |                        |
|                           | |                        |
+---------------------------+ |                        |
      (a) subfigure a         |                        |
                              |                        |
Figure 1: Sed imperdiet, s    |                        |
viverra rhoncus, tellus dui   |                        |
dictum nisl, at porta purus   |                        |
ipsum ac turpis. Fusce auctor |         FIGURE         |
ullamcorper adipiscing. Nunc  |          HERE          |
non quam ac orci egestas con- |                        |
sequat ut eget quam. Cras     +------------------------+
blandit condimentum ornare.         (b) subfigure b
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{figure}  
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XX @{}}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{subfigure a}
    \label{subfig:Xa}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Sed imperdiet, s viverra rhoncus, tellus dui dictum nisl, at porta purus                   |
ipsum ac turpis. Fusce auctor ullamcorper adipiscing. Nunc non quam ac orci egestas consequat ut eget quam. Cras
blandit condimentum ornare.}
\label{fig:X}
    &   \begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=66mm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
            \caption{subfigure b}
            \label{subfig:Xb}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: also works with subfig's subfloat.

Comment: @user3236841, you are right.  BTW, `subcaption` version 1.3 also define `\subfloat` which  enable smooth  transition from the `subfig` package (which is unmaintained for over 14 years) to `subcaption` package. I would stik with `subcaption` and drop `subfig` package.

Comment: i thought subfigure was unmaintained. anyway, good to know that subfig is also so.

Comment: The subfigure package it obsolete,; the subcaption package is current.  OTOH, some document classes are not compatible. with caption and therefore subcaption.  Also note that the subfigure environment requires a width, whereas \subfloat gets its width from the image.